# Wrong installation date and size in Programs and Features

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, date

Nearly every fourth installed program in this list has an estimated size of 7,04GB. Also for some the date gets updated every day. The corresponding reg keys were all set to  "0x0070caf9 (7391993)" for the "estimatedSize" value and the "InstallDate" key was completely missing.

These details are also wrong in the new "Settings -> System -> Apps & Features" list. You can see the problem in the screenshot of my Programs and Features window.

[image]

Why is this happening? Is there a tool to automatically recalculate size and read the date of these programs?

Comment: Similar: http://superuser.com/questions/1049866/can-an-incorrect-program-size-indicate-malware